# Webpack DevServer do not reload page

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack devServer. Every time I change my source files the files get built and the page served by devServer gets reloaded. I do not want devServer to reload the page. I want the devServer to only build and serve files while I reload the page manually.

Here is my webpack configuration for DevServer.

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    port: 8002,
    watchContentBase: false,
  },
```

I tried setting hot: false and hotOnly: false but the devServer still builds and reloads the webpage every time the source file changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two options: `devServer.injectClient` and `devServer.injectHot`. Try to set it to false. No WDS client on a board - no problem. Depends on CLI, check that no HotModuleReplacementPlugin attached.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I was expecting an option such as reloadOnBuild or something like that in the dev server configuration. Anyway I found out that to stop reloading only setting injectClient to false is sufficient.